# Spring - Not a managed type: class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

So, i'm working with 3 different datasources in my application. Initially there were 2, but i had to add another one due to some project changes. After creating a model, a repository, a class to configure this new datasource i'm not able to start my application. It gives the error below:

```
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcConversionService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]: Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transacaoRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class br.com.brb.maf.pix.transacao.model.Transacao
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1072)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1314)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1280)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1094)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1064)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    ... 36 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcConversionService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]: Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transacaoRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class br.com.brb.maf.pix.transacao.model.Transacao
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 52 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcConversionService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]: Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transacaoRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class br.com.brb.maf.pix.transacao.model.Transacao
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1072)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.obtainBeanInstanceFromFactory(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:389)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ef1e37c8.mvcConversionService(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.getInterceptors(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:307)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.requestMappingHandlerMapping(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:258)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.requestMappingHandlerMapping(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:403)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ef1e37c8.CGLIB$requestMappingHandlerMapping$6(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ef1e37c8$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$bc131863.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ef1e37c8.requestMappingHandlerMapping(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 53 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]: Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transacaoRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class br.com.brb.maf.pix.transacao.model.Transacao
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 77 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transacaoRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class br.com.brb.maf.pix.transacao.model.Transacao
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1631)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1086)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories.cacheRepositoryFactory(Repositories.java:96)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories.populateRepositoryFactoryInformation(Repositories.java:89)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories.<init>(Repositories.java:82)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.support.DomainClassConverter.setApplicationContext(DomainClassConverter.java:98)
    at org.springframework.data.web.config.SpringDataWebConfiguration.addFormatters(SpringDataWebConfiguration.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerComposite.addFormatters(WebMvcConfigurerComposite.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.addFormatters(DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.mvcConversionService(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:600)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ef1e37c8.CGLIB$mvcConversionService$35(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ef1e37c8$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$bc131863.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ef1e37c8.mvcConversionService(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 78 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class br.com.brb.maf.pix.transacao.model.Transacao
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:210)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:71)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:68)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:184)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:117)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:99)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:198)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:277)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:263)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:101)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1689)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1627)
    ... 103 common frames omitted
```

The thing is, i am doing the same configuration that i did with my second datasource (the one that is not @Primary), that works ok. So i don't know whats is causing this error. I already tried to use some of the tips that i found here on stackoverflow, like using EntityScan or ComponentScan etc. Here are my classes:

**Transacao.java**

```
package br.com.brb.maf.pix.transacao.model;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Convert;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Immutable;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.convert.threeten.Jsr310JpaConverters.LocalDateTimeConverter;

import br.com.brb.framework.core.entity.AbstractEntity;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Immutable
@Entity
@Table(name = "VW_TRANSACAO_PAGAMENTO_MAF", schema = "GPI")
public class Transacao extends AbstractEntity<Long> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2695172871355012963L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "SQ_TRANSACAO_PAGAMENTO")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "SQ_MENSAGEM")
    private Long mensagemPagamento;

    @Column(name = "CD_IDENT_EVENTO")
    private String transactionId;

    @Column(name = "VL_MENSAGEM")
    private BigDecimal valorTransacao;

    @Column(name = "DT_RECEBIMENTO_ORDEM")
    @Convert(converter = LocalDateTimeConverter.class)
    private LocalDateTime dataRecebimento;

    @Column(name = "CD_CPF_CNPJ_RECEBEDOR")
    private String cpfRecebedor;

    @Column(name = "CD_CPF_CNPJ_PAGADOR")
    private String cpfPagador;

    @Column(name = "CD_ISPB_PAGADOR")
    private String ispbPagador;

    @Column(name = "CD_ISPB_RECEBEDOR")
    private String ispbRecebedor;

    @Column(name = "CD_CHAVE_ENDERECAMENTO")
    private String chaveEnderecamento;

    @Column(name = "CD_CONCILIACAO")
    private String codConciliacao;

    @Column(name = "NO_PAGADOR")
    private String nomePagador;

    @Column(name = "NR_AGENCIA_PAGADOR")
    private Long agenciaPagador;

    @Column(name = "NR_CONTA_PAGADOR")
    private Long contaPagador;

    @Column(name = "NO_RECEBEDOR")
    private String nomeRecebedor;

    @Column(name = "NR_AGENCIA_RECEBEDOR")
    private Long agenciaRecebedor;

    @Column(name = "NR_CONTA_RECEBEDOR")
    private Long contaRecebedor;

    @Column(name = "DS_IDENTIFICADOR")
    private String identificador;

    @Column(name = "CD_FORMA_PAGAMENTO")
    private String codFormaPagamento;

    @Column(name = "SQ_RETORNO_PAGAMENTO")
    private String codRetornoPagamento;

    @Column(name = "SQ_MENSAGEM_RETORNO_PAGAMENTO")
    private Long mensagemRetornoPagamento;

    @Column(name = "CD_IDENT_ORIGINAL")
    private String transactionIdOriginal;

    @Column(name = "CD_STATUS_RETORNO_PAGAMENTO")
    private String statusRetornoPagamentoString;

    @Column(name = "DT_LIQUIDACAO")
    @Convert(converter = LocalDateTimeConverter.class)
    private LocalDateTime dataLiquidacao;

    @Column(name = "DT_CONTABIL")
    @Convert(converter = LocalDateTimeConverter.class)
    private LocalDateTime dataContabil;

    @Column(name = "SQ_DEVOLUCAO_PAGAMENTO")
    private Long codDevolucaoPagamento;
}
```

**TransacaoRepository.java**

```
package br.com.brb.maf.pix.transacao.repository;

import br.com.brb.framework.core.domain.repository.BaseRepository;
import br.com.brb.maf.pix.transacao.model.Transacao;

public interface TransacaoRepository extends BaseRepository<Transacao, Long> {

}
```

**MAFApplication.java**

```
package br.com.brb.maf;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MAFApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    private static final String PROFILE_WEBLOGIC = "weblogic";
    private static final String PROFILE_DEFAULT = "default";

    public static void main(String... args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MAFApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        application.profiles(PROFILE_DEFAULT, PROFILE_WEBLOGIC);
        return application.sources(MAFApplication.class);
    }

}
```

**GpiDatabaseConfigurationStandalone.java**

```
package br.com.brb.maf.config;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedPropertyResolver;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.EnvironmentAware;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "br.com.brb.maf.pix.transacao.repository" })
@Profile("autoContido")
public class GpiDatabaseConfigurationStandalone implements EnvironmentAware {

    private static final String SPRING_DATASOURCE = "spring.datasource.";

    private static final String SPRING_JPA_PROPERTIES = "spring.jpa.properties.";

    private static final String VALIDATE = "validate";

    private static final String HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL = "hibernate.format_sql";

    private static final String HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";

    private static final String HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";

    private static final String HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO = "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto";

    private static final String HIBERNATE_DEFAULT_SCHEMA = "hibernate.default_schema";

    private RelaxedPropertyResolver jpaPropertyResolver;

    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        this.jpaPropertyResolver = new RelaxedPropertyResolver(environment, SPRING_JPA_PROPERTIES);
        new RelaxedPropertyResolver(environment, SPRING_DATASOURCE);
    }

    @Bean(name = "gpiDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.gpi")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "gpiEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
            @Qualifier("gpiDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource);
        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {"br.com.brb.maf.pix.transacao.model"});

        return em;
    }

    Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty(HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO,
                jpaPropertyResolver.getProperty(HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO, VALIDATE));
        properties.setProperty(HIBERNATE_DIALECT, jpaPropertyResolver.getProperty(HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
        properties.setProperty(HIBERNATE_DEFAULT_SCHEMA, jpaPropertyResolver.getProperty(HIBERNATE_DEFAULT_SCHEMA));
        properties.setProperty(HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL,
                jpaPropertyResolver.getProperty(HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, Boolean.FALSE.toString()));
        properties.setProperty(HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL,
                jpaPropertyResolver.getProperty(HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL, Boolean.FALSE.toString()));
        return properties;
    }
}
```

**application.yml**

```
server:
    contextPath: /fraude
    port: 8250
    
spring:
  profiles: default
  application:
    name: MAF
  messages:
    basename: i18n/messages, i18n/messagesWebRest
  batch:
    job:
      enabled: false
  jpa:
    open-in-view: false
    generate-ddl: false
    properties:
      hibernate:
        format_sql: false
        show_sql: false
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
        default_schema: MAF
        hbm2ddl:
          auto: " "          
  cache:
    cache-names: folha
endpoints:
  health:
    sensitive: true
  shutdown:
    enabled: false
applicationProperties:
  mail:
    from: noreply@brb.com.br
  cors:
    allowed-origins: '*'
    allowed-methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
    allowed-headers: Authorization,content-type
    exposed-headers: X-Total-Count, X-Validation-Error
    max-age: 1800
  swagger:
    title: API da aplicação MAF
    description: Documentacao da API da aplicação MAF
    version: 1.0.0
    termsOfServiceUrl: null
    contact: servnuext@brb.com.br
    license: null
    licenseUrl: null
springfox:
  documentation:
    swagger:
      v2:
        path: /api-docs
sga:
  sistema:
    sigla: MAF
  dominio: brb.com.br
  trancodes:
    - name: LOGIN
      code: 1001
    - name: LOGOFF
      code: 1002
  hosts: DAP340218
  ports: 3030
  timeout: 50000
  limiteMaxCon: 10
  timeoutPool: 15000
  mantemConexao: true
authorization:
  activeDirectoryDomain: brb.com.br
  activeDirectoryUrl: ldap://brb.com.br
  timeout:
    refreshToken: 39600
    token: 36000
---  
spring:
  profiles: weblogic
  mail:
    jndi-name: mail/BRB
  datasource:
    maf:
      jndi-name: java/MAFDS
    mobile:
      jndi-name: java/MBKDS
    gpi:
      jndi-name: java/GPIDS  
  cache:
    jcache:
      provider: com.tangosol.coherence.jcache.CoherenceBasedCachingProvider
---
spring:
  profiles: autoContido
  mail:
    host: localhost
    port: 25
  datasource:
    maf:
      url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@DBD340207.brb.com.br:1521/dep1d.brb.com.br
      username: u840280
      password: ENC(V39VJLxZy7PSsgkojKCsR7QUNEaYp4LB)
      driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
      max-active: 2
      max-idle: 1
      test-on-borrow: true
      validation-query: select 1 from dual
      initial-size: 1

    mobile:
      url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@HBD340207.brb.com.br:1521/mcn1h.brb.com.br
      username: u840280
      password: ENC(V39VJLxZy7PSsgkojKCsR7QUNEaYp4LB)
      driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
      max-active: 2
      max-idle: 1
      test-on-borrow: true
      validation-query: select 1 from dual
      initial-size: 1

    gpi:
      url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@HBD340207.brb.com.br:1521/spb1h.brb.com.br
      username: u840280
      password: ENC(V39VJLxZy7PSsgkojKCsR7QUNEaYp4LB)
      driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
      max-active: 2
      max-idle: 1
      test-on-borrow: true
      validation-query: select 1 from dual
      initial-size: 1
---
mensagem:
    url: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
    chave: AIzaSyDe7Zygu8P94nDPVRABS9Y7CU1Kg6D2pyI
    color: navy
    sound: default
    icon: notification_icon 
    contentAvailable: 1
    priority: high
config-proxy:
    proxy: webproxy.brb.com.br
    porta: 8080
    usuario: s_vcbrb
    senha: V1c2b3r4b5
  
---    
spring:
  profiles: h2local
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      hbm2ddl:
        auto: create-drop
  datasource:
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=Oracle
    
---
configConstants:
  dir: /opt/MAF
```

Can anyone enlighten me on this one?

Comment: Why Credentials Are Here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out i had to add the `entityManagerFactoryRef` to the `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation in the config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = { "br.com.brb.maf.pix.transacao.repository" },
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "gpiEntityManagerFactory")
@Profile("autoContido")
```